# r gsub and regex, obating y*_x* from y*_x*_xxxx.csv

Tags: regex, r, gsub

*General situation:* I am currently trying to name dataframes inside a list in accordance to the csv files they have been retrieved from,  I found that using gsub and regex is the way to go.  Unfortunately,  I can’t produce exactly what  I need, just sort of.
I would be very grateful for some hints from someone more experienced, maybe there is a reasonable R regex cheat cheet ?

File are named r2_m1_enzyme.csv,  the script should use the first 4 characters to name the corresponding dataframe r2_m1, and so on…

```
# generates a list of dataframes, to mimic a lapply(f,read.csv) output:
data <- list(data.frame(c(1,2)),data.frame(c(1,2)),data.frame(c(1,2)),data.frame(c(1,2)))

# this mimics file names obtained by  list.files() function
f <-c("r1_m1_enzyme.csv","r2_m1_enzyme.csv","r1_m2_enzyme.csv","r2_m2_enzyme.csv")

# this should name the data frames according to the csv file they have been derived from
names(data) <- gsub("r*_m*_.*","\\1", f)
```

but it doesnt work as expected... they are named r2_m1_enzyme.csv instead of the desired r2_m1, although .* should stop it?

If I do:

```
names(data) <- gsub("r*_.*","\\1", f)
```

I do get r1, r2, r3 ... but I am missing my second index.

**The question:** So my questions is,  *what regex expression*  would allow me to obtain strings “r1_m1”, “r2_m1”, “r1_m2”, ... from strings that are are named r*_m*_xyz.csv

*Search history:* R regex use * for only one character, Gsub regex replacement, R ussing parts of filename to name dataframe, R regex cheat sheet,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your names are always five characters long you could use `substr`:

```
substr(f, 1, 5)
```

If you want to use `gsub` you have to group your expression (via `(` and `)`) because `\\1` refers to the first group and insert its content, e.g.:

```
gsub("^(r[0-9]+_m[0-9]+).*", "\\1", f)
```